# Proposition 1.6 Atiyah

Tags: commutative-algebra

> Let $A$ be a ring and $\mathcal{m}$ a maximal ideal of $A$, such that every element of $1+\mathcal{m}$ is a unit in $A$. Then $A$ is a local ring.

Let $x\in A\setminus\mathcal{m}$ (It is not the quotient ring, but $A$ setminus $\mathcal{m}$). Since $m$ is maximal, the ideal generated by $x$ and $\mathcal{m}$ is $A=(1)$, that is $$(1)=(m,\{x\})$$

**Edit** $(m,\{x\})$ denotes the ideal generated by $\mathcal{m}$ and $x$.

> **Question.** Why there exist $y\in A$ and $t\in\mathcal{m}$ such that $xy+t=1$?

Comment: Do you know what $(m,x)$ means?

Comment: @Nico I clarified what was asked in the question. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: Exact dupe of: [Let $M$ be a maximal ideal in $R$ such that for all $x\in M$, $x+1$ is a unit. Show that $R$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $M$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181171/let-m-be-a-maximal-ideal-in-r-such-that-for-all-x-in-m-x1-is-a-unit-s).  Please search before posting questions.

Comment: By [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1125068/242) the ideal in $\,A\,$ generated by $\,M,x\,$ is the ideal sum $\,M+xA,\,$ therefore $\,1\in M+xA\,\Rightarrow\, 1=m+x\:\!a\,$ for some $\,m\in M,\,a\in A.\,$ See esp. the universal property of the ideal sum explained there, and its analogy with the gcd universal property. That thread should also be added to the dupe list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, given a ring $A$, an element $x \in A$, and an ideal $I \subset A$, we have $$(\{x\}, I) = \{ax + t : a \in A,\, t \in I\}.$$
The above is easy to show. First, check that the set on the right is indeed an ideal. Second, show that any ideal containing $x$ and $I$ must contain the right set.

Apply it to your case by noting that $(\{x\}, \mathfrak{m}) = A \ni 1$.

Comment: *Please* strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.

Comment: OP's question was specifically about one particular step. The linked question is not necessary, @BillDubuque.

Comment: But the answer(s) include this step (and more, including conceptual motivation).

Comment: Could you link the particular answer which does that? @BillDubuque

Answer (score 3):

If $a\in A$, I denote $\bar a$ the class of $a$ in $A/\mathfrak m$. Let $x\in A\setminus \mathfrak m$. Since $\mathfrak m$ is maximal, $A/\mathfrak m$ is a field. Therefore there is $\bar y\in A/\mathfrak m$ s.t. $\bar x\bar y=1$, i.e. $1=(x+m_1)(y+m_2)=xy+t$ where $t=m_1y+m_2x+m_1m_2\in \mathfrak m$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but $A\setminus\mathcal{m}$ is not the quotient ring, but $A$ setminus $\mathcal{m}$.

Comment: @Nat.: I know...

Answer (score 1):

Another solution I thought of: if you're familiar with $J=\operatorname{JacRad}(R)$, this is the radical who's equal to the intersection of all maximal ideals of $R$. One can easily prove that $x\in J\iff$ for every $y\in R$, $1+xy$ is a unit.

We prove $J=m$ in this particular case. The inclusion $J\subseteq m$ is straight from the definition of $J$. Now let $x\in m, y\in R$. From the definition of an ideal, $xy\in m$, and therefore $1+xy$ is a unit. This is true for all $y\in R$, so $J=m$.

Why does this imply that $R$ is a local ring? well assume for a contradiction that it's not. Then we have two maximal ideals, $m, m'$ s.t $m\not\subset m'$ and $m'\not\subset m$. By definition, $J\subseteq m\cap m'\subsetneq m$ - contradiction.